# Replace a String token if found in the set of Strings

Tags: java, set, java.util.scanner

The code below should read each line from the file MainFile.txt, check if each line contains a token from the Set. If it does contain, replace it with "xxx" string. Then write a new file using BufferedWriter.
The output ConvFile.txt is exactly the same as input.

MainFile.txt :

```
car, 18, train, 19, bus,
laptop, 20, tablet, 21, computer,
swim, 22, bike, 23, run,



public class ReplaceWords {

Set<String> wordToReplace;

public ReplaceWords(){
    this.wordToReplace = new HashSet<>();
    this.wordToReplace.add("18");
    this.wordToReplace.add("19");
    this.wordToReplace.add("20");
    this.wordToReplace.add("21");
    this.wordToReplace.add("22");
    this.wordToReplace.add("23");
}

public void redactFile(){
    String inPathname = "E:\\SkyDrive\\Java\\Coding\\FileChgOne\\MainFile.txt";
    String outPathname = "E:\\SkyDrive\\Java\\Coding\\FileChgOne\\ConvFile.txt";
    File inFile = new File(inPathname);
    File outFile = new File(outPathname);

    Scanner bufferedScanner = null;
    BufferedWriter bufferedFileWriter = null;



    try {
        Scanner lineScanner;
        String currentLine;

        bufferedScanner = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile)));
        bufferedFileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outFile));

        while(bufferedScanner.hasNextLine()){
            currentLine = bufferedScanner.nextLine();
            lineScanner = new Scanner(currentLine);
            lineScanner.useDelimiter(",");

            while(lineScanner.hasNext()){
                String currentToken = lineScanner.next();
                if (this.wordToReplace.contains(currentToken)){
                    bufferedFileWriter.write("xxx, ");
                }
                else {
                    bufferedFileWriter.write(currentToken + ", ");
                }

            } 
            bufferedFileWriter.newLine();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception en){
        System.out.println("error: " + en);
    }

    finally {
        try {
            bufferedScanner.close();
            bufferedFileWriter.close();
        }
        catch (Exception en) {
            System.out.println(en);
        }
    } 
} 
}
```

Output ConvFile.txt :

```
car,  18,  train,  19,  bus, 
laptop,  20,  tablet,  21,  computer, 
swim,  22,  bike,  23,  run,
```

Comment: Why the code does not replace: car, 18, train, 19, bus, with car, xxx, train, xxx, bus, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tokens need to be *trimmed*, i.e. whitespace after the comma should be removed when a token is read by the scanner:

```
while(lineScanner.hasNext()){
    String currentToken = lineScanner.next();
    currentToken = currentToken.trim();  // line to add
    if (this.wordToReplace.contains(currentToken)){
        bufferedFileWriter.write("xxx, ");
    }
    else {
        bufferedFileWriter.write(currentToken + ", ");
    }

}
```

You can also do this by updating the delimiter pattern of the `Scanner` as suggested by Marko Topolnik in the comments.

```
lineScanner = new Scanner(currentLine);
lineScanner.useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");
```

`\\s*` means zero or more whitespace characters.

Comment: I would prefer a regex which swallows whitespace to patching up an invalid token.

Comment: That's a nice way to do it as well. I added it to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Actually, I meant `new Scanner(Pattern.compile("\\s*,\\s*")` :) That's the proper way, and it doesn't add a single line of code.

Comment: You mean in the delimiter pattern?

Comment: Yes, sure. That's the most obvious way to do this. For his simple example to work, just adding a single space to his code would be enough, but a regex is much more robust.